# Correct way to initialize localstorage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, local-storage

I am creating an app for google chrome that makes heavy use of local storage and so far worked wonderfully, that is until I cleaned chrome's cache and now no matter what, is not setting any local storage variables where before the cache cleaning it worked beautifully.

I have a file called valtransfer.php that receives php values via something like this:

```
$_SESSION['id_area']=$_REQUEST['id_area'];
```

and then later down the file after the mandatory $(document.ready(function ()) bla bla I have a line like this to pass the values from the php session variable to a local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("id_area",'<?php echo $_SESSION['id_area']?>');
```

As previously said, it worked beautifully... until I cleared cache to test the application, is there something I am missing in order to prepare the browser to work with localstorage like initializing or something?

Comment: Have you got any error on browser console?

Comment: View your source and see what the generated script looks like; maybe you've got the case where if you're out-of-session you never create a new session.

Comment: I'm assuming its not working on multiple attempts after clearing the cache right? Clearing it wiped your session and theres a chance that your localStorage call was happening before your new session was initialized.

Comment: Maybe that could be the problem ginman, let me take a look at that and see if that is where the problem lies, do you suggest that I expressly initialize session before loading all the stuff into local storage? let me try that and will report back.

Comment: if I run localStorage.clear(); then the same thing happens, what could be the implications for this? is it bound to a sessionid?

Answer (score 1):

remove single quote and try like this. because php echo treat as a string

```
var sessionId =  <?php echo $_SESSION['id_area']?>;

localStorage.setItem("id_area", sessionId);
```

Comment: I am wondering how this could be related to clearing cache issue OP has mentioned.

Comment: tried this but did not work... will keep trying with some variations

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
localStorage.setItem("id_area","<?php echo $_SESSION['id_area']?>");
```